# How far up the chain of function calls does an exception travel?

Tags: python, exception

For example, say `func1` calls `func2`, which calls `func3`, which calls `func4`, which raises an exception.

If I put a try/except when calling `func1`, will it catch the exception raised by `func4`?

```
func1 --> func2 --> func3 --> func4 Raises exception
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exceptions propagate until they reach a handler, or until they reach the entry point for the program or thread. If the latter happens, your program will terminate. So, yes, the exception will be caught in func1, unless one of the other functions catches it first.

Answer (score 3):

The exception is propagated up the call stack until a matching `except` block processes it.  It may continue to travel up the stack if the `except` block contains a `raise` directive.